# How to randomize array DURING filter elements (NOT filter array then randomize elements)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, random

for example, suppose I have array :[13,7,15,1,10,7,3,18,4,20], I have 2 requirements :

1. only select elements >10
2. randomize result array

normal way to do:

```js
let arr=[13,7,15,1,10,7,3,18,4,20];
let result=[];
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]>10){
      result.push(arr[i]);
    }
}

for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
  const r=Math.floor(Math.random()*result.length);
  const temp=result[i];
  result[i]=result[r];
  result[r]=temp;
}
for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    console.log(result[i]);
}
```

But I believe I can do it at simpler way : I can put it into a random position DURING filtering instead of randomise the whole array after getting all result, I tried:

```js
let arr=[13,7,15,1,10,7,3,18,4,20];
let result=[];
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]>10){
      result.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*result.length),0,arr[i]);
    }
}

for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    console.log(result[i]);
}
```

But I found it is not working : the last element is always 13:

```
18
20
15
13

20
15
18
13
```

whats wrong with the idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.random()` is always less than `1.0` (even if 1.0 is included, it is nearly impossible to get one). Therefore `Math.floor(Math.random()*result.length)` never equals `result.length` since you use `floor()`. That means you never insert new element into the position after the last existing element, while the last existing element is always the first element you added, i.e. `13`

To get a random integer ranging from `0` to `result.length` inclusive and equal probability, use `Math.floor(Math.random() * (result.length + 1))`